# Какие есть способы обойтись без UI для файла .exe чтобы принять от пользователя единственный аргумент

Tags: ui, exe

Имеется программа на rust, которая компилируется в файл ".exe", который, по запуску, обрабатывает файлы в заданной пользователем папке без установки программы на компьютер. Мне нужно чтобы программа могла как-то принять адрес папки от пользователя, но мне абсолютно не хочется писать UI для этого. Какие есть варианты?

Может есть какая хитрая возможность в свойствах самого файла, например, пользователю устанавливать в качестве метаданных путь к папке или еще какой способ? Не хочется из-за такой мелочи писать UI.
Переделать файл в приложение командной строки тоже не готов.

Есть такое решение проблемы как поместить ".exe" в нужную папку с файлами, но мне, к сожалению, оно не желательно. Это корпоративная сеть и пользователи буду забывать удалять файл после завершения его работы, что приведет к тому что файл ".exe" расплодится по разным адресам папок в корпоративной сети, что нежелательно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запуск с параметром в который пользователь передаёт путь к папке, если он
запускает приложение через консоль, либо в ярлыке приложения можно задать путь и при необходимости пользователь может его изменить самостоятельно.

В приложении нужно реализовать изъятие пути к файлу из массива аргументов командной строки.

Из-за этого UI точно писать не надо и дополнительные файлы не нужны.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Изъятие пути к файлу из массива аргументов командной строки это только при консольном запуске или при запуске по ярлыку тоже можно сделать чтобы в массив записались данные хранящиеся в ярлыке? О каком поле ярлыка вы говорите чтобы пользователю можно было там задать путь? Наверное "Рабочая папка"?

Comment: @Сергей в свойствах ярлыка есть поле объект - там записан путь к вашему приложению. После .exe, через пробел, можно дописать аргументы запуска(скорее всего путь нужно будет обернуть в двойные кавычки). Вот как это примерно должно выглядеть: https://nastroyvse.ru/opersys/win/kak-propisat-parametry-zapuska-v-yarlyke.html

Answer (score 1):

я бы добавил config.txt и с него парсил параметр